# Why does the MySQL telegram bot not work?

Tags: python

I'm making a telegram bot in python. The fact is that information should be output from the users table, but only the 'id' label should be output. And when I translate row to a row, the data is output, but when changing/adding information, the bot outputs the same information (I work with mysql via worbench). Here bot.py:

```
import telebot
import config
import pymysql
import os 




from telebot import types

import pymysql.cursors

# Connect to the database
try:
    connection = pymysql.connect(host='localhost', user='root', password='password', database='ts', charset='utf8mb4', cursorclass=pymysql.cursors.DictCursor)
print("connected")

try:
    with connection:
        cur = connection.cursor()
        cur.execute("SELECT  * FROM users ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1")

        result = cur.fetchall()



        bot = telebot.TeleBot(config.token)



        @bot.message_handler(commands=['session'])
        def lalala(message):
                for row in result:
                     bot.send_message(message.chat.id, row)


        bot.polling(none_stop=True)


finally:
    connection.close()
```

except Exception as ex:
print("conn refused")

Thank you in advance!

Comment: are you sure you have the right server and or password

Comment: Yes, I checked everything.

Answer (score 0):

You can't ave a try without an except or finally.

so changing the code a bit you can connect to a local dataase

```
import telebot
import config
import pymysql
import os 




from telebot import types

import pymysql.cursors


try:
    connection = pymysql.connect(host='localhost', user='root', password='passpord', database='ts', charset='utf8mb4', cursorclass=pymysql.cursors.DictCursor)
    print("connected")
except:
    print("not connected")    


try:
    with connection:
        cur = connection.cursor()
        cur.execute("SELECT  * FROM users ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1")

        result = cur.fetchall()



        bot = telebot.TeleBot(config.token)



        @bot.message_handler(commands=['session'])
        def lalala(message):
                for row in result:
                     bot.send_message(message.chat.id, row)


        bot.polling(none_stop=True)


finally:
    connection.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

It turned out that in each function it is necessary to reconnect to MySQL

Code:

```
from telebot import types
import pymysql.cursors


bot = telebot.TeleBot(config.token)





@bot.message_handler(commands=['session'])
def lalala(message):
    connection = pymysql.connect(host='localhost', user='root', password='password', database='ts', charset='utf8mb4', cursorclass=pymysql.cursors.DictCursor)
    cur = connection.cursor()
    cur.execute("SELECT  * FROM users ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1")
    result = cur.fetchone()

    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, f'{result}')


bot.polling(none_stop=True)
```